# Remote container mount network share from Windows host

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows, vscode-remote

### Problem Description

I would like to specify a mount to a network share from the devcontainer.json "mounts" property so that I can write scripts that pull files from that network share and can run on multiple host machines.

I can see that VSCode Remote Containers is purely passing through the "mounts" property value to the `docker run --mount` parameter.  So if I can find a way to get that to work, then I should be set.

I can mount a network share from a WSL2 distribution with `sudo mount -t drvfs //myserver/projects /mnt/p` and mount it in a container with `docker run --rm -it --mount source=/mnt/p,target=/mnt/p,type=bind,readonly=true ubuntu:18.04 bash` and I can list that directory in the container to get the contents of the network share.  But that only works when I execute the docker commands from within the WSL2 distribution terminal window.  For this to work from VSCode remote containers, I need this to work from the Windows host machine.  And I have yet to find any equivalent commands that work from the standard Windows Command Prompt.

### What I've tried

These were all attempted from the Windows command prompt on the host machine.
And I have a mapped network drive from `P:` to `\\myserver\projects`.

```sh
# Even with the mount to the network share still present in the primary WSL distribution
docker run --rm -it --mount source=/mnt/p,target=/mnt/p,type=bind,readonly=true ubuntu:18.04 bash
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /mnt/p
```

```sh
docker run --rm -it --mount source=\\myserver\projects,target=/mnt/p,type=bind,readonly=true ubuntu:18.04 bash
docker: Error response from daemon: \\myserver\projects%!(EXTRA string=is not a valid Windows path).
```

```sh
docker run --rm -it --mount source=//myserver/projects,target=/mnt/p,type=bind,readonly=true ubuntu:18.04 bash
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /myserver/projects.
```

```sh
docker run --rm -it --mount source=P:\,target=/mnt/p,type=bind,readonly=true ubuntu:18.04 bash
ls /mnt/p
# Empty directory
```

```sh
docker volume create --opt type=cifs --opt device=//myserver/projects projects
docker run --rm -it --mount source=projects,target=/mnt/p,type=volume,readonly=true ubuntu:18.04 bash
docker: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/projects/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount //myserver/projects:/var/lib/docker/volumes/projects/_data: invalid argument.
```

```sh
docker volume create --opt type=cifs --opt device=P:\ projects
docker: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/projects/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount P:\:/var/lib/docker/volumes/projects/_data: invalid argument.
```

```sh
New-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath \\myserver\projects -LocalPath R:
docker run --rm -it --mount source=R:\,target=/mnt/p,type=bind,readonly=true ubuntu:18.04 bash
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /run/desktop/mnt/host/uC/myserver/projects.
```

```sh
New-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath \\myserver\projects -LocalPath R:
docker run --rm -it --mount source=R:\,target=/mnt/p,type=bind,readonly=true ubuntu:18.04 bash
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /run/desktop/mnt/host/uC/myserver/projects.
```

And I've tried all combinations of `\` vs `/` with similar errors

Comment: I have encountered the same issue probably a year ago, and since then try from time to time to resolve it, so far without any success. With the update to WSL2 and the possibility to let docker run on the WSL2 backend, I naively thought it might be now possible to use `sudo mount -drvfs` from within the docker container but no...